# Explanation of Karush Kuhn Tucker conditions?

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Can somebody please explain how we get the Karush Kuhn Tucker conditions, especially the complementary slackness, without using the crutches of jargons? I am not well versed in what dual problems or primal problems would be interpreted as neither do i know or/and understand what duality gap or LP is supposed to even mean. Internet is filled with only jargons but I am just trying to understand how to optimize a function given inequality constraints and I come across KKT and would like to know how they are arrived at. I would be able to understand calculus 1,2,3 and linear algebra

Thank you in advance

Comment: You ask for an explanation "without using the crutches of jargons", but your question appears to contain some.

Comment: That is all that i have read after googling on the topic. I know those words exist. That is all. But i think an explanation for someone like me might exist, so thought ill ask pundits of maths. NLP engineer here without any background in non-linear programming